# How do I invoke a method in another thread?

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

I have the following classes:

```
        using System;
        using System.Windows.Forms;

        namespace FastEyeControl
        {
            public partial class ConnectView : Form, IConnectView
            {
                private IConnectPresenter m_Presenter;

                public ConnectView()
                {
                    InitializeComponent();

                    m_Presenter = new ConnectPresenter(this);
                }

                public string Hostname
                {
                    get
                    {
                        return m_Hostname.Text;
                    }
                }

                public int Port
                {
                    get
                    {
                        return Convert.ToInt32(m_Port.Text);
                    }
                }

                public void ShowMessage(string message)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(message,
                                    "Success",
                                    MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                                    MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }

                public void ShowError(string message)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(message,
                                    "ERROR!",
                                    MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                                    MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }

                private void m_ConnectButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    m_Presenter.ConnectButtonPressed();
                }
            }
        }
```

The presenter class:

```
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;

        namespace FastEyeControl
        {
            public class ConnectPresenter : IConnectPresenter
            {
                private IConnectView m_View;
                private IConnectModel m_Model;

                public ConnectPresenter(IConnectView view)
                {
                    m_View = view;
                    m_Model = FastEyeClient.Instance;
                }

                public void ConnectButtonPressed()
                {
                    m_Model.Connect(m_View.Hostname, m_View.Port);
                }

                private void ConnectionComplete(object sender, ConnectionEventArgs e)
                {
                    // Code here indicating whether connection was successful and informing the view.
                    // i.e...

                    if (e.IsConnected)
                    {
                        m_View.ShowMessage("Successfully connected.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        m_View.ShowError("Unable to connect.");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The model code runs in another thread. The problem is that when I call m_Model.Connect(), I'm calling code that's usually running in another thread within the main thread still (the UI thread). This is not a database connection. This is a TCP/IP connection to a server. If I set a variable within the model, then I am doing this from the UI thread which is not thread safe.

I know that with user controls, they have InvokeRequired and Invoke/BeginInvoke operations that will handle this situation. But that is for user controls only. I know you can't just interrupt another thread in the middle of its execution and tell it to call another method instead. I basically want the non-UI thread to call the Connect code somehow.

Just as a test, I tried using a delegate (fire off an event whenever I want to connect) and when I look in the debugger, the Connect code is still running in the UI thread.

I need a multi-threaded event queue essentially. What's the best way to achieve what I want to do here? Thanks!

Comment: I didn't notice that feature before. Thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
 public void ConnectButtonPressed()
            {
                var threadedTask = () => m_Model.Connect(m_View.Hostname, m_View.Port);
                threadedTask.BeginInvoke(null,null);
            }
```

This will, no question, use a background thread from the ThreadPool to do the work. Maybe you had tried to call the delegate directly, or called Invoke() on it; that will execute the delegate synchronously.

Now, BeginInvoke is simple to set up, but it has its limitations; you cannot cancel execution of the background thread, and if it throws an exception you cannot catch it in the invoking thread.

Comment: @Andrew That code is creating an anonymous delegate (threadedTask) which includes the code to connect the model.  It then calls BeginInvoke on the the anonymous delegate which is a non block call and will spin up a thread (the framework does it for you) and execute the code in your delegate.

Answer (score -2):

You can use [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

Comment: I looked at BackgroundWorker. It looks like it's designed for running a time-consuming task in the background that will eventually complete. There's no way to pass information back to the UI thread other than the progress and such. Could I subclass it to have it pass more information back to the UI thread? I would want the background worker to live as long as the application lives. Is this appropriate?

Comment: @Andrew You can pass in a parameter to the BackgroundWorker and the DoWorkEventArgs parameter to that event will give you back the parameter you passed in when you created the BackgroundWorker.  You could use that "state" object to communicate between the UI thread and the backgroundworker.  Just remember to use Invoke whenever making a cross thread call.

Comment: @Andrew: When you call the BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress, you specify an object for the userState parameter. Using it, you can pass whatever information you want.

Comment: @Andrew: I wont recommend using the same BackgroundWorker for the whole application. Use a seperate control for each group of tasks is better.

Comment: I basically want a permanent thread running in the background (lives as long as the application lives). Would BackgroundWorker be OK for this? I'm not trying to put all of the application in the BackgroundWorker. Just a portion of it for background processing (network communication).

Comment: Maybe I could use BackgroundWorker. Then that thread will have a thread-safe queue in it. Basically, events are added to the queue and the thread will keep dequeuing the events until the queue is empty. Once it's empty, the thread will just sleep until more items are added to the queue. The problem with this though is that I can no longer put in an infinite loop that is listening for connections or data from the server, etc in this thread.